# Show out of table only when equal to 0

Tags: php, mysql

At the moment i'm showing a slider out of my database on my website with this piece of code:

```
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM seo_slider ORDER BY id";
$stmt = $pdo->query($query);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($result as $row) {
?>

<ul class="rslides">
    <li><figure><a href="<?php echo $row['link']; ?>"><img src="http://www.onderdemolen.nl/images/slider/<?php echo $row['id']; ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $row['titel']; ?>" /></a>
    <div class="caption"><div class="titel"><h1><?php echo $row['titel']; ?></h1></div><div class="beschrijving"><h3><?php echo $row['caption']; ?></h3></div></div></figure></li>
</ul>

<?php
}
?>
```

In my table seo_slider I also have a field called "actief" in here it says 0 or 1. I want that the slides on my website only to show when the slide has 0 in "actief". And when it says 1 the slide won't show on my website. I already tried some things but can't get it to work.
Would be nice if somebody could help me!

Comment: So add a [WHERE clause](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/where.php) to your database query.... this really is a databases 101 question

Comment: You already tried "some things"..... what things did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Put it within an if statement:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    if($row['actief'] == 0){
?>

<ul class="rslides">
<li><figure><a href="<?php echo $row['link']; ?>"><img src="http://www.onderdemolen.nl/images/slider/<?php echo $row['id']; ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $row['titel']; ?>" /></a>
<div class="caption"><div class="titel"><h1><?php echo $row['titel']; ?></h1></div><div class="beschrijving"><h3><?php echo $row['caption']; ?></h3></div></div></figure></li>
</ul>

<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM seo_slider WHERE actief=0 ORDER BY id
```

That will make the database return only registers where the column you want is equal to 0.
It's better than checking the value in PHP code.

Comment: Well that wasn't that hard xD thanks! I was trying all kinds of stuff with if statements and equals... My PHP knowledge isn't that big yet.